# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when overriding Equals

Tags: c#, overriding, runtime-error

Im trying to override Equals in my Class and I get this error which I do not understand *"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"*

My code :

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return this.Equals((Chapter)obj);
}

public bool Equals(Chapter other)
{
    return this.KeyFromChapterName == other.KeyFromChapterName &&
        this.Name == other.Name;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT 1 (stacktrace) :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Wurth.TarifImageOdsFormatter.Process.Items.Chapter.Equals(Chapter other) in C:\Projet\KeyAccountExporter\Wurth.KeyAccountExporter\Wurth.TarifImageOdsFormatter.Process\Items\Chapter.cs:line 32
   at Wurth.TarifImageOdsFormatter.Process.ProgramV2.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projet\KeyAccountExporter\Wurth.KeyAccountExporter\Wurth.TarifImageOdsFormatter.Process\ProgramV2.cs:line 110
```

Line 110 is `if(myChapter.Equals(OtherChapter)` and Line 32 is where I start :

```
public bool Equals(Chapter other)
{
  return this.KeyFromChapterName == other.KeyFromChapterName &&
   this.Name == other.Name;
}
```

Comment: What if `other` is `null`?

Comment: `this` is never going to be null, so that's not the culprit.  What else in your code.  What else could be null here?

Comment: You aren't passing in `null` are you (or a variable that may be null)?

Comment: have you tried to step it trough in debbuger? and now if you pass not a `Chapter` in `obj` you'll get `InvalidCastException`

Comment: I runned step by step and checked every value. Im sure when I check myChapter.Equals(OtherChapter) that both are Chapter and none are null.

Comment: @WizLiz what does the stack trace say?

Answer (score 1):

*"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"* means that you're trying to dereference a `null` reference. In other words trying to access something that is `null`.

In the other function you are referencing `other.KeyFromChapterName` and `other.Name`. If `other` is null here it will also throw that exception.

edit:

other option is if one of the properties' implementations, e.g. `KeyFromChapterName` references an object that is `null`.

edit2:

to clarify, the property's getter could reference something that is null:

```
public String KeyFromChapterName
{
    get
    {
        //I don't know what types you are dealing with here, but as an example,
        //if chapterNames is a dictionary but it's null, then this would throw
        //the nullreferenceexception up to your Equals function.
        return chapterNames[name];
    }
}
```

Comment: `(Chapter)obj` that actually won't throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: My downvote was locked, Just to remove  that I edited your answer.